# Include NULLs in comparison

Tags: sql, db2

My DB2 SQL requires me to report a set of values if they are different.
For example:

```
 Current Assessment  Previous Assessment
 20                  25
 19                  19  
 30                  32
 30                  _________
```

The above returns line 1 and 3. Not line 2 obviously. But I need it to return Line 4 as well... but as it is comparing to a Null it doesn't return it.

How to get around this?

Comment: What is the query that you are using? To compare something with NULL you need to use the `IS [NOT] NULL` predicate, not equality.

Comment: `where current_assessment is distinct from previous_assessment`

Comment: or `select * from t except select * from t where current_assessment = previous_assessment;`

Comment: I am using AND Current Assessment <> Previous Assessment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you compare numerics values

```
WHERE COALESCE(current_assessment, previous_assessment +1, 0) <> 
      COALESCE(previous_assessment, current_assessment +1, 0) ;
```

if you compare chararcteres values

```
WHERE COALESCE(current_assessment, previous_assessment || 'X', '') <> 
      COALESCE(previous_assessment, current_assessment || 'X', '') ;
```

with this method, null=null and not necessery to choice an arbitrary value for coalesce.

Else if you are sure your columns not contains one XVALUE you can do it:

```
WHERE ifnull(current_assessment, XVALUE) <> ifnull(previous_assessment, XVALUE);
```

the best method is

```
Where current_assessment<>previous_assessment or (current_assessment is null and previous_assessment is not null) or (current_assessment is not null and previous_assessment is null)
```

Comment: Interesting. Ill test it later. In the end, due to time constraints I just redid it with a Not Exists to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It can be handled using `IS NULL` & `OR` condition

Code

```
Where (  ("Current Assessment" <> "Previous Assessment") 
      OR ("Current Assessment" IS NULL)
      OR ("Previous Assessment" IS NULL)
      )
```

Comment: This leads to the resource limit being exceeded if entered as is, and doesn't affect the outcome if I do it as AND (Current <> Previous OR Current IS NULL OR Previous IS NULL)

Comment: @Ardia - Am not a expert in `db2` but do you have any index in `Current Assessment` or `Previous Assessment` column ?

Comment: Current and previous assessments are themselves large derived selects. No index.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following. The coalesce will ensure it compares only values that are different. If both the values are null then as well the query will treat them as match

```
WHERE COALESCE(current_assessment, <value>) <> 
    COALESCE(previous_assessment, <value>) ;
```

Please note the Value should be a non occurring value probalby a very low negative number like -999999

Comment: yes.. sorry.. my mistake. the best answer would be to use WHERE COALESCE(current_assessment, <value>) <> COALESCE(previous_assessment, <value>). And that value should be a non occurring value probable a low negative value

Comment: Does not work. It wont display the Current Assessment Value/Previous NULL value.

Comment: @Ardia the query woudl work with the sample data you provide. Just use `0` or `-1` in place of `<value>`.